# Proving inequalities by induction

Tags: inequality

I'm having trouble understand the inductive when proving inequalities; Here's an example:

Show that $2^n \gt n^2 $ for any integer $n \gt 4 $.

Well for the basis $n=5$, it shows: $32>25$

Now, assume: $2^{n+1} \gt (n+1)^2 $ for some integer $n$.

Well,  **RHS**:

$$(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n +1$$

And the problem starts there. I cannot seem to "pull" out my inductive hypothesis from here. Any input?

Comment: It is not a bad thing take the case $n+1$ as my induction hypothesis but it is more common if you take the case $n$ as it. And then you work with the case $n+1$ using the case $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your induction hypothesis should be that $2^n>n^2$, not that $2^{n+1}>(n+1)^2$; you should be using the induction hypothesis to **prove** that $2^{n+1}>(n+1)^2$.

To do this, notice that $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n$, so if $2^n>n^2$, as we are assuming, then $$2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n>2n^2\;.$$ You want to show that $2^{n+1}>(n+1)^2$; if you could show that $2n^2\ge(n+1)^2$, you’d be done, because then you’d have

$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n>2n^2\ge(n+1)^2$$

and hence $2^{n+1}>(n+1)^2$. Thus, it all boils down to showing that $2n^2\ge(n+1)^2$, i.e., that $2n^2\ge n^2+2n+1$. This, of course, is equivalent to showing that $n^2\ge 2n+1$, i.e., that $n^2-2n-1\ge 0$. Now $n^2-2n-1=(n-1)^2-2$, and this is greater than or equal to $0$ provided that $n$ is ... what?

Comment: The point where  I get lost is here: $2n^2\ge(n+1)^2$ . How did the $\ge\ (n+1)^2$ come into play?

Comment: @Dimitri: Once you prove that $2n^2\ge(n+1)^2$ for the values of $n$ that are of interest, you can use that fact to complete the chain of inequalities $$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n>2n^2\ge(n+1)^2\;,$$ thereby showing that $2^{n+1}$ is greater than $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Comment: @Dimitri: You’re welcome!